# MessagingCentre from MVVM to MainPage in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I need to use the `MessagingCentre` in `Xamarin` to allow my ViewModel to send a message to my MainPage, as part of a button's command.

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I subscribing to the `MessageCentre`, looking for a message of "Focus", which then sets the focus of the form to an Entry control, called txtFirstName.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "Focus", (sender) => { txtFirstName.Focus(); });
    }
```

In my ViewModel, the command is:

```
 private void ClearFormCommand(object obj)
{
    FirstName = string.Empty;
    Surname = string.Empty;
    Age = string.Empty;
    AboutMe = string.Empty;

    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Focus");
}
```

However, there is an error on `this` in the `MessagingCentre.Send` line.

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ViewModel' to 'AppName.MainPage'

What do I need to replace `this` with in the VM to send the message to `MainPage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `<MainPage>` generic with your viewmodel type `ViewModel` (for both subscribe and send call)

Comment: Close - I had to change it to `.Subscribe<ViewModel>` in `MainPage`, then `.Send(this, "Focus")` in my ViewModel

Comment: Alright good, but as your exception also states, you were giving a wrong type. So always look at the Method signature and you may find it out urself next time :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **this** inside **MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Focus");** is the instance of your MainPage. As per your code, it seems that Send and Subscribe are fine.

Inside the MainPage constructor, you are assigning the Bindingcontext to instance of ViewModel. This code is suspicious here. Just debug once more your code and try to figure out the actual root cause or provide the full code.

For more about Message Center, you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

Hope this will help you.
thanks